# jQuery DataTables show no results message on 404 ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using DataTables with:

```
$t = $('#users-table').DataTable({
    'paging'    : true,
    'searching' : true,
    'ordering'  : false,
    'info'      : false,
    'serverSide': true,
    'processing': true,
    'ajax'      : {
        'url'   : 'http://localhost/api/users',
        'type'      : 'GET',
        'dataSrc'   : 'users',
        'error': function() {
              // how can i handle the 404 response and show the no results found message?
        }
    }
    ...
```

The server will return a 404 not found response if the query had no results. I'm trying to show the no results message and remove the current data from the table, but instead data will remain the same in the table on an error response like that.

Edit:

I am using the search functionality like this:

```
$('#data-filter').keyup(function() {
  $t.search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

So when no results are found with a query word a 404 is returned.

Comment: Why would the server respond with a 404 if no results are found? Why wouldn't it return the number 0 in its response?

Comment: Why you down-voted the question? Is that a reason?

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. Can you answer my question?

Comment: I'm not asking the wrong question, i'm asking if something like that can be implemented. I did not implement the server side, but a 404, some might say that it is not wrong in such a case.

Comment: Michalis, trust me, I have a decade's worth of experience as a full-stack web developer. It most certainly is incorrect. https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/7c/4b/3e/7c4b3e0aa22b07ef1100e9994f05e390.jpg

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: All: You should vote to close this question, but please don't flag it for moderator attention: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253605/109941

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **IMPORTANT**

It makes little to no sense to return `404` error when there are no results. See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32815209/3549014) for reasons why.

It would be better to program your script to return empty array as value for `data` parameter and indicate that there are no results (`recordsFiltered`) and total size of result set (`recordsTotal`), see [Returned data](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) for more information.

> **WORKAROUND**

However, you can suppress the alert message and clear the table on error using `ajax` option as outlined below:

```
"ajax": {
    'url': 'http://localhost/api/users',
    'type': 'GET',
    'dataSrc': 'users',
    'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $('#example').DataTable().clear().draw();
    }           
},
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69rs83wr/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: What if the web server returns a genuine error? Or genuine 404?

Comment: @JimG., as noted in the answer I see little to no sense to using this solution, but it is possible to implement.

Comment: This is an XY question, and you're doing the OP a disservice by inviting him down this path. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Answer (score 1):

> You should fix the server-side code to return zero rows when it it should return zero rows.

- A '404' HTTP status code is reserved for situations when a web asset or entity is 'Not Found'.
- In this case, your entity is found, but there is nothing to return.
- It's a different scenario, and a '404' error code would be incorrect and would be tantamount to immediate technical debt.

Comment: I totally agree with this answer, but unfortunately, it's not always easy to convince the other members on the team that a certain approach isn't right... on top of that, there might be deadlines that need to be met, and the other members might not have time to address these types of issues.  As the OP said, another team is in charge of returning the data, so he might just be stuck with what they've given him.